# How to plot the surfaces this image in gnuplot

Tags: math, plot, gnuplot

Could you please help me with plotting the surfaces from this image[image]. The cone thing is z = x^2+y^2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code? Have you checked the gnuplot homepage www.gnuplot.info and basic tutorials?

Comment: @theozh for now i can draw the x^2+y^2 surface but can't draw the x+y=1 though i can draw x+y

Answer (score 0):

You could try parametric plot. Check `help parametric`.
But to be honest, I don't have a good idea how to plot your sketch. Actually, it is not really a surface or mesh but the outline of a solid body. The following attempt is not satisfying but maybe a starting point. I hope somebody can show a better solution.

**Code:**

```
### parametric plot
reset session

set view 60,120, 1.3
set view equal xyz

unset border
unset tics

set arrow 1 from 0,0,0 to 2,0,0   lc "black" lw 2
set arrow 2 from 0,0,0 to 0,2,0   lc "black" lw 2
set arrow 3 from 0,0,0 to 0,0,2   lc "black" lw 2

set xyplane relative 0
set parametric

x(u,v) = sin(2*pi*u)*sqrt(v)
y(u,v) = cos(2*pi*u)*sqrt(v)

set pm3d depthorder
set hidden3d

set samples 30
set isosamples 30
set urange[0:1]
set vrange[0:2]

splot  x(u,v), y(u,v), v    with lines lc "black", \
          1-u,      u, v/2  with lines lc "blue"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]